# PDO prepared statement in UPDATE Multiple ID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update, prepared-statement

I am Developing a simple shopping system and using `PDO`.
But I can't seem to use PDO while updating using multiple values ...
Look here :

```
    // GET MESSAGES ID AND REPLACE '-' WITH ','
    $mid = explode("," , str_replace( '-' , ',' , $mid ));
    $isread = "read";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `mshop_pms` SET `readperm` = ? WHERE `mid` IN (?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($isread, array($mid)));
```

How can I do this? and do this :

```
$stmt->execute(array($isread, $mid));
```

Without explode It just Update first row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work in this way. You need to iterate over the exploded array, then keep on updating.

Here's an example:

```
// GET MESSAGES ID AND REPLACE '-' WITH ','
$mid = explode(",", str_replace('-', ',', $mid));
$isread = "read";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `mshop_pms` SET `readperm` = :readperm WHERE `mid` = :mid");
//now update and iterate
foreach ($mid as $m) {
    $s->bindParam(':readperm', $isread);
    $s->bindParam(':mid', $m);
    $s->execute();
}
```